# html2pdf: how to show the pdf (to allow the user to save it) and save it on the server

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, html2pdf

How your doing?
Good!
Today I'm looking to use html2pdf. It works pretty well and I can show/save the pdf but I can't do both! That's a problem and I don't know what should I do.
I'm using the library with symfony and this code works:

```
ob_start();
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/feuille.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
$html2pdf = new \Html2Pdf_Html2Pdf('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);

// $result = $html2pdf->Output($_POST["fournisseur"].".pdf", 'F'); //save on server
$result = $html2pdf->Output($_POST["fournisseur"].".pdf"); //show the page on browser
exit();
```

The commented code works only if I comment the following one...
So, do you have any solution to allow both of those line to work together?

Thank you for your help!

PS: it also only works if I add the exit() function at the end, so if anyone knows something about it, may he speaks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can Use following method...

```
$result = $html2pdf-&gt;Output($_POST["fournisseur"].".pdf", 'F');
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
echo file_get_contents($_POST["fournisseur"].".pdf");
```

Comment: Please Note this is Not suitable for very large files...a few MB's will be ok

Comment: Ok thank for the information, I'll only use it for 1page at the time so it should not be a problem. ^^

Comment: The `$result` variable is unused.

Comment: should've been `$html2pdf->` instead of `$html2pdf-&gt;` (encode symbol `^`)

Answer (score 0):

i have use something similar library before, tcpdf.

i just save the file in server, after that echo a link to browser or redirect user with php.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `output` function without parameter, you will be able to see the PDF, without saving it.

You can add the second function `$html2pdf->Output($_POST["fournisseur"].".pdf", 'F')` to save the PDF on your disk.

About the `exit`, it may come from your `ob_start()` call. This function open a response buffer, without sending it. The `html2pdf output` function don't need `ob_start` function ;)

Answer (score 0):

or you could try this

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('example.pdf');
```

Comment: or use wkhtml2pdf - it does exactly what you want

Comment: or you could try this

    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('example.pdf');

This works only if you want to show the pdf but not save it in the same time.^^

Answer (score 0):

In symfony2 we use such code to show pdf to use

```
return new Response(file_get_contents($fileData['path']), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
```

For download file

```
$response = new Response(file_get_contents($path));
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', mime_content_type($path));
$response->headers->set(
    'Set-Cookie',
    'fileDownload=true; path=/');
$response->headers->set(
    'Content-Disposition',
    sprintf('attachment;filename="%s"', utf8_decode($name))
);

$response->send();
```